# Modify Laravel Query to get properties & images in single query instead of separate sub query for images

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am getting properties from table 'properties' first, then running inner query to get images from a separate table 'property_images'. This is a slow approach. Guide me how I can get properties & images in a single query in my api request ?

```
public function searchProperty(Request $request){
        if(count($request->all()) > 0){
            $properties = array();
            $properties = \DB::table('properties')
            ->where($request->all())
            ->get()->toArray();
            $prop_ids = array();
            if(isset($properties) && !empty($properties) && count($properties) > 0){
                foreach($properties as $prop){
                    array_push($prop_ids, $prop->id);
                }
                $prop_images = \DB::table('property_images')
                    ->whereIn('property_id', $prop_ids)
                    ->get()->toArray();
                if(isset($prop_images) && !empty($prop_images)){
                    foreach($prop_images as $imgs){
                        $upload_path = storage_path() . '/uploads/property/' . $imgs->property_id .'/'.$imgs->property_image;
                        array_push($properties, $upload_path);
                    }
                }
                echo '<pre>'; print_r($properties); exit;
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => true,
                    'data' => $properties->toArray()
                ], 400);
            }
        }
        else{
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'No data available'
            ], 500);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, It should must work for you to get all properties along with its all images in just single query. Images will be comma separated & you will get it with single product row. You will have to explode by comma.If you are writing any api you can concat complete url with images.

```
    DB::table('properties')
    ->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(property_images.property_image) as 
    property_images, properties.*')
    ->leftJoin('property_images', 'property_images.property_id', '=', 'properties.id')
    ->groupBy('properties.id')
    ->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: In case of no image, it will return NULL